# how much string that length is n can we create from A and B that string will not contain two A consecutively

Tags: string, algorithm

how much string that length is n can we create from A and B that string will not contain two A consecutively.

```
For example;
if n=1 , strings are A ve B    =>  it has 2 solutions
if n=2 , strings are AB, BA, BB    =>  it has 3 solutions
in n=3 , strings are ABB, ABA, BAB, BBA, BBB  =>  it has 5 solutions ... etc.
```

I need a decrease and conquer algorithm , can you help me please ?

Comment: You should think about how you can construct strings length N from strings length N-1 and N-2 depending on the first character or characters of those strings. (An off the top of my head hint: N-2 might not be relevant, I'm not sure). Or alternatively it might be easier to think about how many strings there are that do contain consecutive As and then subtract that from 2^N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if n=1, result[1] = 2
if n=2, result[2] = 3
if n=3, result[3] = 5
if n=4, result[4] = 8
if n=5, result[5] = 13
```

so, this generates a Fibonacci sequence.

```
result[1] = 2
result[2] = 3
result[n] = result[n-1]+result[n-2];
```

Closed form of Fibonacci sequence:

[image: Closed form of Fibonacci sequence]

Comment: IMO that's only half the answer: you've found a sequence that fits five observed values from the pattern, but you haven't explained why that works, or why that's going to hold for any n. Which is fairly obvious, but you're going to have to include that if you want full marks in your homework.